# How to find the first and last ID of MYSQL Table Enteries for a specific date?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get the range of entries by their IDs created in a MYSQL table on a specific date in a PHP file. How can this be achieved? If required, assume there is a column in the database that lists the date when an entry is created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do a query like this:

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM tablex WHERE entrydate = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```